# ESXi RAID on Intel ICH10R

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, intel

I have an Asuse P8P67 motherboard with onboard intel RAID controller, I'v configured a RAID 0 in "intel rapid storage - option rom" but ESXi installation wizard shows the physical disks only not RIAD volume. and RAID is not working after installation.

How can I use Intel ICH10R raid controller in VMware ESXi?

Comment: Typically if it's not on the HCL (hardware compatibility list) it's not going to happen, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is compatibility going beyond VMWare's HCL - a "[whitebox HCL](http://www.vm-help.com//esx40i/esx40_whitebox_HCL.php)" has been assembled by the community listing a lot of components which ESX(i) has been found to work with. It also has something to say about software RAID controllers:

> this list includes a number of SATA
>   controllers that provide RAID
>   functionily via a  software component
>   in the drivers supplied with the
>   controller. Examples would be the
>   Intel ICH  series and the nVidia MCP
>   series. ESX 4.x and ESXi 4.x do not
>   support that software RAID 
>   functionality thus you will only be
>   able to access the individual drives
>   connected to controllers such as
>   these.

Answer (score 0):

ESXi tends to only support tier-1 RAID controllers (like LSI/PERC/etc.), but you may have some luck finding it [here](http://www.vm-help.com).

Another (and in my opinion, better option) is to setup an iSCSI capable NAS like OpenFiler, FreeNAS, or NexentaStor (which uses ZFS; all kinds of awesome right there).

Answer (score 0):

In short, because intel is lying to you. It isn't an actual controller, it's a piece of embeded software using your computer as the controller. (CPU/MEMORY etc.)

http://linux.yyz.us/why-software-raid.html